# wrong encoding error for a certificate in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, ssl-certificate, pkcs#12

I made a big mistake when I've open a certificate created for a TLS connection inside IntelliJ.

Now, I've always an error:

> Error:(1, 1) The file was loaded in a wrong encoding: 'UTF-8'

But when I try to change the encoding, I don't find something like "PKCS12" or "JKS".

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: `I don't find something like "PKCS12" or "JKS".` these are not the text encoding. These are archive file format for storing many cryptography objects, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12

Comment: Use encoding widget to switch the file encoding: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html#single-file

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the solution but unfortunately, I didn't find the correct encoding for my file. So, I've delete the file and re-add it inside the project and no mistake... Not the best solution but it works.